# Volley - Cancelling request on fragment stop

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

I have numerous fragments in the app that make Volley requests.

Is it possible to automatically cancel all requests when a fragment exists?

currently in all such fragments I have the following code (not verbatim as I'm away from my actual machine);

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  if (request != null)  {
    request.cancel();
  }
}
```

Comment: According to me each query added to queue has a tag. And you can get that particular request from  the queue and then cancel the request

Comment: @PriyaSinghal thanks but in this case  still have to manually cancel the request on each close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't cancel requests in onPause() as according to the documentation, your fragment can be partially visible when onPause() is called.

Instead cancel all requests in onStop():

```
@Override
protected void onStop () {
super.onStop();
if (mRequestQueue != null) {
    mRequestQueue.cancelAll(this);
   }
}
```

Ref: [Cancel a Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#cancel)

Comment: This is correct. Cancel request on onStop. And you (@StackOverflowed) should cancel the request by TAGs. Follow the guidelines on android developers.